# characters in p-groups

Tags: p-groups

I would like to know that some examples of p-groups with $|cd(G)| = dl(G)=3$, such that $cd(G)$ to denote the set of degrees of the irreducible characters of $G$ and $dl(G)$  to denote the derived length of $G$.

Comment: There are 9 isomorphism classes of such $G$ with order 128. One is the Sylow 2-subgroup of $S_8$ (also known as the wreath product of $D_8$ and $C_2$). Another is the wreath product of $Q_8$ and $C_2$.